# After Ajax call back color picker does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, silverstripe

I am using Silver Stripe 2.4.7 and I am trying to add a color picker using the jQuery color picker extension provided on the silver stripe site. I have added the color picker and the color picker is working fine no issue. But the problem is when I am going to some other pages from the settings page of admin part and again come back to where I have added my color picker then my color picker does not work. The other whole page is called through Ajax.

For example say I am in setting and if I go in the pages the pages is loaded through Ajax and not page refresh and when I come back to settings this is also done through Ajax in silver stripe. At this point I am unable to use the color picker. The input is there and when clicked the color picker doesn't pops out.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Check if there is any error in the console (firebug, developer tools, etc)

Comment: welcome to so ... can you provide  code you tried ?

Comment: It was simple.. $(document).onAjaxComplete(function(){});